# Get STATUS change dates of issue in JIRA using REST API?

Tags: jira

I'm using JIRA APIs to determine the dates that my issues status has changed. So far after getting the issue from this endpoint

```
GET /rest/api/2/issue/{issueID}
```

I get the final status and the date it was set. However I can't see the interim statuses. Does anyone know how to see the interim statuses and the dates of an issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no changelog implementation for Jira Server. It is available for Jira Cloud. You need to use some plugins. You can create your custom REST API endpoint with Scriptrunner.

Answer (score 0):

Do a
GET /rest/api/2/issue/{issueID}?expand=changelog

You will get the complete changelog of your issue